# How do I know, where are my components used?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently working on quite a big react.js system/project with a lot of reused components and there are no unit tests or documentation whatsoever. My worries starts when I change (fix) one of these components for one specific use case and in 3 other places which I don't know at the time component broke down.

It would be amazing to have some tool which tells me, in which all places is some specific component use, so I can test it in all cases.

Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Though this may not be particularly helpful, I normally end up doing a search. I haven't yet found a better way, and I don't think any tools exist for this purpose.

Comment: This question is more about your IDE than react itself. Try to google "<your ide name> find usage". Using webstorm I can find a component usage pretty easily; not sure about others IDE however

Comment: example with VS Code: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tips-and-tricks#find-all-references

Comment: Thanks, yes this is exactly what I'm using now, but it's not really that helpful if I don't know for example in which parent component is child component used and so on, I mean you can find it, but it's quite a lot of searching..

Comment: if you're using VSCode, you can install a react/node plugin and just "cmd"/"ctrl" + "click". you can also search for a certain file via "cmd"/"ctrl" + "t"

Answer (score 8):

Use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd> after selecting class, function or method to see usage in a folder if you are using VsCode.

Comment: Or select the thing you want to search for (class, function, method) and press CMD + SHIFT + F if you are on Mac OS.

Comment: This just opens a search with the results for that item. There's no way to see some number in the UI next to the function/component definiton?

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio code press shift+f12 after selecting class, function or method to see usage in a folder if you are using VsCode.