# Can i know where i have imported my component in react js?

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code

I was working on a react js project...now I have deleted a component and it's showing an error after a while as previously I have imported the same component somewhere else too. I wanted to know if there is any way to find out where I have imported that component using a direct key or something rather than doing with the hard way and going each file one by one.
Also, the editor I'm using is vscode if this information is helpful.

Comment: You can probably know it by looking at the import path.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution someone posted earlier, it was helpful.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56626745/how-do-i-know-where-are-my-components-used)

thanks